# Calculating for the academic year using php

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate for the current academic year of a school. Well, school's academic year normally falls between August and May. Assuming we are in 2013 in the month of August, the academic year becomes 2013-2014. Also when we are in the month of May in the year 2013 then the academic year becomes 2012-2013.

I want to use php to derive the current academic year, this is what i have so far. I want to know if there is a better solution or I am on the right path.

```
$currentYear=date("Y");
$currentMonth=date("m"); 
if($currentMonth >="08") 
     echo ($currentYear).'-'.($currentYear + 1);
if($currentMonth < "08")
     echo ($currentYear-1).'-'.($currentYear);
```

Comment: you could write unit tests to test your assumptions.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Just that you don't need quotation marks around numbers. Just compare directly: `if($currentMonth >=8)`

Comment: alright,then why would some body down vote, this really unfair!!

Comment: Downvotes are not saying that your code is bad, rather that the question doesn't have a clear answer other then "your code looks okay" or "this is how i would do it".

Comment: That said, I would recommend using `date('n')` instead of `date('m')`; it will return the current month without leading zeroes; then you can use @Hanky웃Panky's suggestion to compare with numbers directly.

Comment: alright @Jack, but i have answered the question, just that i needed the better way to go, so down voting me doesnt really make sense here.

Comment: @George That falls in the category of a code review rather than having tried something that didn't result in the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Jack So how do i reveiw my codes, where should codes be pasted for review??

Comment: @George See [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Aright.Thanks so much, but i didnt no.Aniwae thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
date('Y').'-'.(date('Y')+1);
```

Comment: This is more of a comment.

Comment: Sorry I am just two days old on stackoverflow

Comment: Well, you have enough rep to post comments, that's the good news :)

Comment: Hmm php is amazing i am crazy for it

Comment: Thanks guys.. I forgot this, but please is it ok to save year value in mysql table as a character (char)

Comment: @George Years are numbers, so store them as `int unsigned`.

Comment: Btw, OP already uses `date('Y')` in the code; there's no need to use it twice.